# Rewriting tensor equation.

Tags: tensors

If I have the tensor equation
$$T_{kij}+T_{jik} = S_{ijk}$$
where $T$ is symmetric on the last two indices $T_{ijk}=T_{i(jk)},$
then is there a way to write $T_{ijk}$ in terms of only the tensor $S?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You easily observe that $S$ is also symmetric in the last two indices, $S_{ijk}= S_{i(jk)}$.

The solution is $$T_{kij}= \frac12 (S_{ijk} +  S_{jik} - S_{kij}).$$ You can check by inserting in your equation;

You obtain
$$T_{kij}+ T_{jik} =\frac12 (S_{ijk} +  \underline{S_{jik}} - \underline{\underline{S_{kij}}}) + \frac12 (S_{ikj} +  \underline{\underline{S_{kij}}} - \underline{S_{jik}}) = \frac12(S_{ijk} + S_{ikj}) = S_{ijk}.$$